# Invalid frame header

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to make a real time application. I am using NodeJS as a server and Socket.IO, to achieve my real time functionality.

The problem is I am getting error as:

```
 WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:1234/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: Invalid frame header
```

I tried many things, like changing https to http, lowering the Socket.IO version, etc., but nothing worked for me. Please help me with the cause of the problem, so that I can pinpoint the error in my application. I don't want to go for other COMET protocols.

Comment: How is your server implemented?

Comment: @robertklep using socket.io only

Comment: But _how_? Can you show its code?

Comment: @robertklep actually there is nothing to show the code i am just doing io.connect from ui and its giving me the error, can you just give me the probable causes of this error

Comment: Probable causes: incorrectly configured reverse proxy, incorrectly configured HTTP server, using `wss://` against an HTTP server or `ws://` against an HTTPS server, using an incorrect catch-all route, not connecting the `socket.io` server correctly to the HTTP/HTTPS server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

well it was my mistake only i was initializing the server with socket.io twice which was causing the issue

Comment: took me hours to find this answer!! but you saved my life. your the only one i found that had the same issue! :)))) i owe you a coffee

Answer (score 17):

Use the same version of `socket.io` and `socket.io-client` on both server and client.

Comment: You are a wise person, a hero and a life saver <3

Comment: Thanks, I am happy that your issue has been resolved by this answer

Answer (score 5):

For me the answer was that I was connecting with a client that was version 2 and the server was running version 4. As [per the docs](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-installation/) I had to enable `allowEIO3` on the server

Answer (score 2):

Problem I had was when using create-react-app and running it with "npm run start" to get the live refresh local version during development it uses by default a websocket with the `/ws` path. This conflicted with my app that was also using this path. So when you use the `setupProxy.js` with http-proxy-middleware it was forwarding both to the api server, which caused the invalid frame headers.

The solution was in the web app change the websocket route to something else like `/websocket` instead and in `setupProxy.js` set it up like this:

```js
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(
        // Do not use `/ws` as it conflicts with create-react-app's hotrefresh socket.
        createProxyMiddleware('/websocket', {
            target: 'http://localhost:3000',
            ws: true,
            changeOrigin: true,
        })
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Changed socket io to use its standalone server and it worked for me. Initially added it to server created by express.
This code fixed the problem..

```html
const io = require("socket.io")();

//listening socket io on different port
io.listen(4000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently having the same issue when using **socket.io-client**. I've solved my problem by following the directions below.

You can try setting opts.transports to only websocket in client:

```
io.connect(url, { transports: ['websocket'] }); // default is ['polling', 'websocket']
```

Ref: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/issues/1097#issuecomment-301301030

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue, but in my case I was sending files over from javascript to flask back end in python and my chunk size was too large. It seems socket.io limits it to 1MB per frame sent over the network, which includes socket.io headers. Sending chunks that are 1MB or larger seem to mess up the existing headers, so I reduced the chunk size and it worked out just fine.

Client (vanilla JS used with Socket.io CDN version 4.7.5)

```
const form = document.getElementById('main-form')

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const langSelect = document.querySelector('#language');
  const language = langSelect.value;
  const currencySelect = document.querySelector('#currency');
  const currency = currencySelect.value;
  sendFile({ language, currency });
});

const socket = io('http://localhost:5000'); // Adjust the server URL accordingly

function sendFile(moreDataObject) {
  const fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
  const file = fileInput.files[0];
  if (!file) return;

  // if CHUNK_SIZE >= 1MB then the socket header gets overwritten and throws errors
  const CHUNK_SIZE = 1024 * 512; // 0.5MB
  const totalChunks = Math.ceil(file.size / CHUNK_SIZE);
  const fileId = `${file.name}-${Date.now()}`; // Unique ID for the file upload

  for (let i = 0; i < totalChunks; i++) {
    const blob = file.slice(i * CHUNK_SIZE, (i + 1) * CHUNK_SIZE);
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e) => {
      const base64Content = e.target.result.split(',')[1];
      socket.emit('file_chunk', {
        fileId: fileId,
        chunkIndex: i,
        totalChunks: totalChunks,
        chunkData: base64Content,
        fileName: file.name, // Consider sanitizing on the server
        ...moreDataObject // Including the language and currency
      });
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  }
}
```

Server (using Flask v3.0.2, Flask-Cors v4.0.0, Flask-SocketIO v5.3.6)

```py
import os
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
import base64

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")

# Dictionary to hold file chunks
file_chunks = {}


@socketio.on("file_chunk")
def handle_file_chunk(data):
    print(f"\n\nLanguage: {data['language']} Currency: {data['currency']}\n\n")
    # Extracting the chunk data
    file_id = data["fileId"]
    chunk_index = data["chunkIndex"]
    total_chunks = data["totalChunks"]
    chunk_data = base64.b64decode(data["chunkData"])
    file_name = data["fileName"]  # Consider sanitizing this

    # Initialize the file's chunk list if not already
    if file_id not in file_chunks:
        file_chunks[file_id] = [None] * total_chunks

    # Store the chunk data
    file_chunks[file_id][chunk_index] = chunk_data

    # Check if all chunks have been received
    if all(chunk is not None for chunk in file_chunks[file_id]):
        upload_path = "uploads"
        if not os.path.exists(upload_path):
            os.makedirs(upload_path)

        # Sanitize the file_name or ensure it's safe before appending it to the path
        safe_file_name = os.path.join(upload_path, os.path.basename(file_name))

        # Reassemble the file
        with open(safe_file_name, "wb") as file:
            for chunk in file_chunks[file_id]:
                file.write(chunk)

        print(f"Received and reassembled {safe_file_name}")

        # Cleanup: remove stored chunks to free memory
        del file_chunks[file_id]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app)
```